# Переопределение методов класса Iterator

Tags: java

Как переопределить методы класса `Iterator` (а именно: `next()`, `hasNext()`, ну и `remove()`), если я создал свою коллекцию, которая наследует `AbstractCollection`? С такого наследования вытекает слудующий вопрос: как переопределить методы `AbstractCollection`(а именно: `size()`, `iterator()`)?

Требуется, конечно же, не просто переопределить, а так, чтобы с моей коллекцией можно было работать как и со стандартными!

Буду благодарен за толковые подсказки.

Comment: Так вопрос-то в чём заключается? Почему вы не можете просто взять и реализовать эти методы? Реализация этих методов от вашей коллекции зависит.

Comment: Ну а как их реализовать чтобы с их помощью можно было нормально работать с коллекцией? Как сделать чтобы next() возвращал именно следующий элемент коллекции, hasNext() что есть еще элементы в коллекции (хотя бы один), и т.д.???? Вот в чем вопрос заключается, я же это и сказал, просто не так прямо, как в этом сообщении!

Comment: Это зависит от способа реализации Вашей коллекции. Что именно не получается ?

Comment: Нужно создать коллекцию, в которую нельзя добавлять одинаковые обьекты(сравнительно по какому то полю конешно, у меня например по имени). Я создал коллекцию, добавил в неё элементы, но когда компилирую, конешно же компилятор материться, ведь нужно переопределить методы next(), hasNext(), а там наверное нужно будет и size(), и iterator(). Метод add() я переопределил, но

Я не могу бросить код, так как тут у вас ограничения на количество знаков... (Нафиг они в таком форуме)

Comment: Я не могу бросить код, так как тут у вас ограничения на количество знаков... (Нафиг они в таком форуме)

Под текстом Вашего вопроса есть ссылка "*править*". Кликните ее и вставляйте код в текст вопроса. Для форматирования выделите его (mouse selection) и нажмите кнопочку "101010" над формой ввода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator` это не класс, а интерфейс - то есть просто декларация методов без их реализации. `AbstractCollection` это абстрактный класс, то есть класс имеющий абстрактные (опять же без реализации) методы. Интересующие вас методы `size()` и `iterator()` абстрактные - то есть без "мяса", без реализации. Посему речь идет не переопределении, а написании их с "нуля".

Декларация вашей коллекции должна быть примерно такой:

```
public class MyCollection extends AbstractCollection
{
}
```

Как только вы это напишите, то любая вменяемая IDE сама допишет скелеты требуемых для реализации методов. Ну а дальше пишите.

Если захотите воспользоваться какими то наработками в API Java то надо наследовать от класса который уже наследует от `AbstractCollection` - скажем `ArrayList` - там все эти методы уже реализованы и можно ими воспользоваться типа через super.iterator() или [заглянуть в исходники](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) `ArrayList` и подсмотреть как там все сделано

Comment: Спасибо ребята, кароче теперь я проблему решу! Мне нигде нормально так не ответили как у вас, везде или воду льют, или вообще не шарят! Вроде бы такой "жизненный вопрос", но ничего в нете не мог найти! Одним словом, выручили вы! Ответы получили самые что ни есть толковые! Спасибо вам еще раз)))

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть два варианта. Во-первых, вы можете не делать свою коллекцию, а испольовать обычный HashSet. Но тогда вам придётся модицифировать свой класс (который вы храните, назовём его Item) так, чтобы hashcode() и equals() работали в соответствии с тем полем, по которому над сравнивать

```
class Item {
    private String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Item) {
            Item another = (Item) obj;
            return name.equals(another.name);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Второй способ - это действительно сделать свою коллекцию. Её можно сделать, например, так

```
public class MySet extends AbstractSet<Item> {

    private Map<String, Item> c = new HashMap<String, Item>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return c.values().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return c.size(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Item item) {
        if (!c.containsKey(item.getName())) {
            c.put(item.getName(), item);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Item) {
            return c.containsKey(((Item)o).getName());
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Item) {
            c.remove(((Item) o).getName());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        c.clear();
    }
}

class Item {
    private String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за толковый ответ!!!))